# jQuery each loop through only groups not for each radio button?

Tags: jquery, selector

Why does this selector goes through each radio button instead just to loop as much as there is different groups? http://jsfiddle.net/nardev/3AsCm/2/

This is how i test it:

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" />
<input type="radio" name="group1" />
<input type="radio" name="group1" />

<input type="radio" name="group2" />
<input type="radio" name="group2" />
<input type="radio" name="group2" />
```

js:

```
$('input[name^="group"]').each(function(index){
    console.log(index +": "+$(this).attr("name"));
    $(".h").append(index +": "+$(this).attr("name") +"<br />");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector selects all input elements withe name attribute starting with `group`, it doesn't filter out unique names

If you want to print only different group names then

```
var group = {};
$('input[name^="group"]').each(function (index) {
    var name = this.name;
    if (!group[name]) {
        group[name] = true;
        $(".h").append(index + ": " + name + "<br />");
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rZc3t/)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the selector asks for all input tags that have a name that starts with group.
You have to be more specific and include the number (1/2) if you only want input tags from each unique group.

ex:

```
$('input[name="group1"]').each(function(index){
    console.log(index +": "+$(this).attr("name"));
    $(".h").append(index +": "+$(this).attr("name") +"<br />");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name^="group"]').
```

by this it selct all radio button whose `name` is start with `group`  so it will take all radio button

reference  **[attribute-starts-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can also detect the different groups by the following method too,

```
var xName = '';

$('input[name^="group"]').each(function (index) {
    if (xName != this.name) {
       xName = this.name;
       $(".h").append(index + ": " + xName + "<br />");  
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rZc3t/7/)